# Replace all occurrences of a given string with matching records in a string

Tags: php, arrays

My problem is this: I have a string. In this string there are IDs which are inside two %-characters. For each ID there are matching records in a multidimensional array. The array key is the ID between the two %-characters. For each occurrence within the string I want to replace the ID and the 2 % characters with the corresponding record.

Example of the string chain:

```
Lorem %1% dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam %5% eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore %7% aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

Example of the array with the user data:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 0 [data] => LOREM ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [data] => IPSUM ) )
```

I already tried to convert the whole string chain into an array using explode and then iterate through the array entries using a foreach loop. Unfortunately the blanks in the string cause me problems, so that explode doesn't work as it should and I can't get all words in an own array entry.

So far I have a function "getContents()" with which I can get all occurrences of the 2% characters with the ID together from the whole string chain. I use the IDs to extract the respective records from the database and store them in an array.

```php
  function getContents($str, $startDelimiter = '%', $endDelimiter = '%') {

    $contents = array();
    $startDelimiterLength = strlen($startDelimiter);
    $endDelimiterLength = strlen($endDelimiter);
    $startFrom = $contentStart = $contentEnd = 0;

    while (false !== ($contentStart = strpos($str, $startDelimiter, $startFrom))) {

      $contentStart += $startDelimiterLength;
      $contentEnd = strpos($str, $endDelimiter, $contentStart);

      if (false === $contentEnd) {
        break;
      }

      $contents[] = substr($str, $contentStart, $contentEnd - $contentStart);
      $startFrom = $contentEnd + $endDelimiterLength;

    }

    return $contents;

  }

  function getUserDataFields($input, $userid)
  {

    $dataFields = $this->getContents($input);

    foreach($dataFields as $key => $field){
      $datas[$key] = ["id" => $key, "data" => $this->userController->getCustomerDataByFieldId($userid, $field)];
    }


//At this point I want to loop through the whole string chain in some way to replace All Ids with the corresponding separators with the matching records and then return the whole string from the function.

  }
```

Comment: What is the key doesn't exist in the array? What do you want to happen?

Comment: So am not confused you want to replace all `%:number%` with the value of array index of `:number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can pass in an array, string and the delimiter wrapper and if it finds it in the array, then it will replace it; otherwise leave it alone.

```
$str = 'Lorem %1% dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam %0% eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore %7% aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.';

$arr = [
  [
    'id' => 0,
    'data' => 'LOREM'
  ],
  [
    'id' => 1,
    'data' => 'IPSUM'
  ]
];

$newStr = replaceContent($arr, $str);

echo $newStr;

function replaceContent($arr, $str, $startDelimiter = '%', $endDelimiter = '%') {
  preg_match_all("#{$startDelimiter}([\d]+){$endDelimiter}#", $str, $matches);

  foreach($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    $index = array_search($value, array_column($arr, 'id'));
    if ($index === false) continue;

    $str = str_replace($matches[0][$key], $arr[$index]['data'], $str);
  }

  return $str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract an array indexed by the `id` and then replace using the number found:

```
$array = array_column($array, 'data', 'id');
$text = preg_replace_callback('/%(\d+)%/', function ($m) use($array) {
                                               return $array[$m[1]];
                                           }, $text);
```

Or just a simple loop using those indexes:

```
foreach(array_column($array, 'data', 'id') as $key => $val) {
    $text = str_replace("%$key%", $val, $text);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to check if index exists in your function because it will return undefined index if it doesn't exist in the array. Example: return isset($array[$m[1]]) ? $array[$m[1]] : '';